# Can't find the simple algebra mistake

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to find the expected value of $X^2+Y^2$, where their joint distribution is given by density $f(x,y)=2/L^2$ on $0\le x \le y\le L$ for some $L>0$ given, $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

The area is given by the bottom-left triangle of a $L\times L$ square, which we can represent either as

1. $x\in[0,L]$ and $y\in[0,L-x]$, or
2. $y\in[0,L]$ and $x\in[0,y]$.

However, I am getting two different answers for the two different approaches. I am hoping someone can point out the mistake in my algebra, which I include below. (Sorry if this is too elementary -- shaking off some rust!)

By 1, $$\frac{L^2}{2}E(X^2+Y^2)=\int_0^L\int_0^{L-x}(x^2+y^2)dydx=\int_0^L (x^2y+\frac{1}{3}y^3)|_0^{L-x}dx$$
$$=\int_0^Lx^2(L-x)dx+\int_0^L\frac{1}{3}(L-x)^3dx=\frac{L}{3}x^3|_0^L-\frac{1}{4}x^4|_0^L+\frac{1}{3}\int_0^Lu^3du$$
$$=L^4\biggr(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}\biggr)=\frac{1}{6}L^4.$$

By 2,
$$\frac{L^2}{2}E(X^2+Y^2)=\int_0^L\int_0^y(x^2+y^2)dxdy=\int_0^L(\frac{1}{3}x^3+y^2x)|_0^ydy$$
$$=\int_0^L\frac{4}{3}y^3dy=\frac{1}{3}L^4.$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $0<x<y<L$ means: 1. $x\in [0 , L], y\in[x , L]$

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 \leq x \leq y \leq L$ means: 1. $x\in [0 , L], y\in[x , L]$ so:

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{L^2}2\mathsf E(X^2+Y^2)&=\int_0^L\int_x^L(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\int_0^L x^2(L-x)+\tfrac 13(L^3-x^3)\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\tfrac 13\int_0^L (L^3+3Lx^2-4x^3)\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=L^4/3\end{align}$$